# how to create a new map with constructor?

Tags: java

I am wanting to do two things

1. Create a private instance variable which is a map
2. To create an empty instance in my constructor that impliments a map and assigns it to the previous private instance variable.

The Private instance I have is

```
private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus = 
                      new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>();
```

but how would create an instance variable in the constructor that would reference the private variable thesaurus upon the constructors creation.

For example

```
public class Book{

    private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus = 
                           new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>();

public Book(){

    super();    
    /* What do i put here as an empty instance 
     * variable that implements a map and how 
     * do i assign it to thesaurus? 
     */
}
```

Comment: What you have now should work.  What problems are you having?

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear what you're asking, but here are some points:

- You can't *declare* an instance variable in a constructor; you have to do declare it as a member of the type (i.e. as a field).
- You can *assign values* to already declared instance variables in a constructor.
- You *don't have to* assign values to instance variables in a constructor; you can do it at the declarations.

---

When you write something like this:

```
public class Book{

   private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus =
      new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>(); 
   //...

}
```

Then you've declared `thesaurus` to be an instance variable of `class Book`, and you also initialized its value to be a `new HashMap`. Since this field is `final`, you can no longer set its value to be anything else (barring reflection-based attacks).

You can, should you wish to choose so, move the initialization into the constructor. You can do this even when the field is `final` (subject to various definite assignment rules).

```
public class Book{

   private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus;

   public class Book {
      thesaurus = new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>();
   }
   //...

}
```

Something like this is done sometimes when e.g. the creation of the initial value may throw a checked exception, and therefore needs to be put in a `try-catch` block.

Another option is to initialize fields in an instance initializer block:

```
   private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus;

   {
      thesaurus = new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>();
   }
```

And yet another option is to refactor said instance initializer block into a helper method:

```
   private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus = emptyMap();

   private static Map<Character, Sorted<String>> emptyMap() {
      return new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>();
   }
```

#### References

- [JLS 8.3 Field Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3)

  - [8.3.1.2 `final` Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.2)
  - [8.3.2 Initialization of Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2)
- [JLS 8.6 Instance Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.6)
- [JLS 16 Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html)

#### Related questions

- [Initialize final variable before constructor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677595/initialize-final-variable-before-constructor-in-java)
- [Proper way to declare and set a private final member variable from the constructor in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749588/proper-way-to-declare-and-set-a-private-final-member-variable-from-the-constructo)
- [In Java, can a final field be initialized from a constructor helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859577/in-java-can-a-final-field-be-initialized-from-a-constructor-helper)
- [Java - Can final variables be initialized in static initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339932/java-can-final-variables-be-initialized-in-static-initialization-block)
- [Best Practice: Initialize class fields in constructor or at declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551/best-practice-initialize-class-fields-in-constructor-or-at-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

You are already initializing your thesaurus variable with a map.  You can move it to the constructor, like:

```
public class Book
{
  private final Map<Character, SortedSet<String>> thesaurus;

  public Book(){
    this.thesaurus = new HashMap <Character, SortedSet<String>>();    
  }
}
```

There's no need to change, though.  Either way, the instance field will be initialized every time an instance is created.  Also note that you don't need `super()` here since it's implicit.